# How to make WPF DataGrid save changes back to database?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, dataset

I have search around and found some answers, but I think my case a bit different. Here is my XAML tag:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myPath}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

and here is the C# code:

```
    a = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Patients", c);
    d = new DataSet();
    a.Fill(d, "myPath");
    dataGrid1.DataContext = d;
```

The DataGrid show data ok. How do I save changes bac to database? I have try:

```
a.Update(d);
```

But there is a exception say:

> Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I should search harder be for post, anyway here is the solution:

```
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(a);
    a.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
    a.Update(d);
```

For more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx